# PIL quality issue

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm creating a thumbnail for an image using the following code:

```
im = Image.open('original.jpg')
im.thumbnail((600,473), Image.ANTIALIAS)
im.save('original_thumbnail.jpg', quality=95)
```

**Original Image**
[image: Original Image]

**Thumbnail**

[image: Thumbnail]

As you can see, the quality of the thumbnail is unlike the original. I'm guessing it has something to do with the color profile attached to the original image not being copied over but that's a just guess. Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: i bet it has something to do with that last line where it says "quality=95"

Comment: Not that I can tell. If I take it out, same result.

Comment: Nothing. And PIL recommends that you not go over 95.

Comment: you can't explicitly specify a quality value of less than 100% and ask why the quality isn't the same.

Comment: Quality is the wrong word to use, but there's definitely something wrong with the colours.

Comment: @yurib - but the type of difference is key here: it's the color.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PIL convert picture leads to bad result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543426/pil-convert-picture-leads-to-bad-result)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the similar question previously asked on SO:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8544762/974317

Seems that [PyCMS](http://www.cazabon.com/pyCMS/) - a module that provides color profile management - should work for you.